# Toggle bold highlighting for comments in term/GUI

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

Currently, I use this:

```
map <F7> <Esc>:if has("gui_running")<Bar>hi comment gui=bold<Bar>else<Bar>hi comment cterm=bold<Bar>endif<LF>
```

It turns comments bold in terminal or in GUI when I press `<F7>`.

And I would like it also to toggle the bold text. Is there a way to do this?

Something like:

```
if hi comment gui == bold
    hi comment gui=none
else
    hi comment gui=bold
endif
```

Comment: Note you can just use `:hi comment gui=bold cterm=bold`, no need for the `if` statement here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current settings of a highlight group with the [`:highlight`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#E415) command. For example:

```
:highlight Comment
Comment        xxx term=bold ctermfg=4 guifg=Blue
```

This will just output the text; there is (as far as I know), no VimScript function to get the same text in a string, but not all is lost, since we can use the [`:redir`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Aredir) command to redirect the output of a command to a variable.

We can then match this, and call the appropriate `:highlight` command.

Putting that all together, we end up with this function:

```
fun! ToggleHighlight()
    " Redirect output of :highlight to l:current
    redir => l:current
        silent highlight Comment
    redir END

    if l:current =~# '\(cterm\|gui\)=bold'
        highlight Comment gui=none cterm=none
    else
        highlight Comment gui=none cterm=bold
    endif
endfun
```

And you can map this function to `<F7>` with:

```
noremap <F7> <Esc>:call ToggleComments()<CR>
```

Comment: Ah, I figured there would be some way of getting the state of the `cterm` or `gui` attributes.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. But I think nomap is wrong. Can you correct it please? I dont know which map command I would want to use here.

Comment: @Mike Oops, sorry, I meant to use `noremap`, which is the same as `map` but non-recursive. See [Learn VimScript the Hard way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/03.html) chapters 3 through 5 (especially chapter 5) to learn why you should always use `noremap` and never `map`.

Comment: You can use `:echo synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID('Comment')), 'bold', 'gui')` to check for bold mode for gui. See the help at `:h synIDattr` for all the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

This mapping is probably more suited to a mapping which calls a function, since it contains so many commands.  Here is my best shot at this:

```
" This just uses the call command to run the ToggleBoldComments function
nnoremap <F7> :call ToggleBoldComments()<CR>

function! ToggleBoldComments()
    " Make a variable in the current buffer to keep track of whether the
    " comments are bold or not.
    if !exists("g:comments_bold")
        let g:comments_bold = 0
    endif

    " If comments aren't already bold, make it so.
    if g:comments_bold == 0
        let g:comments_bold = 1
        hi comment gui=bold cterm=bold
        return 0
    elseif g:comments_bold == 1
        " Same, except the other way around.
        let g:comments_bold = 0
        hi comment gui=none cterm=none
    endif
endfunction
```

Here are the relevant help topics *(I recommend you read these if you want to know more about how this mapping works)*:

- `:help :function`
- `:help :call`
- `:help exists()`
- `:help g:`
- `:help internal-variables`
- `:help :highlight`