# How to get bold comments in vim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, formatting, comments, plugin

I am trying to add bold comments to my vim files. What i mean, is to be able to get something like this:

[image]

I saw other articles like [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3743/36607) that allow to toggle bold comment.

The proposed solutions from those articles act as follows: when i toggle the function, ALL comments we be bold, or ALL comments we be normal. So that looks like:

[image]

However, i am trying to only make certain parts of comment bold, like in the first image.

**How to i do this?**

**Edit: Thanks to the help of @klaus, a possible solution is to do:**

```
sy match myBoldComment '-\+\s\+[^-]*\s\+-\+' | hi myBoldComment cterm=bold gui=bold
```

**Obviously, the pattern is up to you :)**

Comment: That's a vimscript specialty (sort of): take a look at `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/vim.vim` and `:g/vimCommentTitle`

Comment: @needle, check `:h :hilight`. It will explain how the code is highlighted in vim. Then check the file Ben mentioned, `vim.vim`. There is a highlight-group called `vimCommentTitle`, which is made into a reference of another highlight group called `PreProc`. So, if you want your vim comments to have their titles in bold, you have to do `:hi Preproc cterm=bold, gui=bold`. Report back if it works or not. Mind you, it's only gonna work with comments in filetype vim (I think).

Comment: I remember seeing some config from a vim-guru so old I cannot even remember his name. He had a function to highlight the visually selected text in different color. I'm sure you could modify that function to embolden the selected text instead of highlighting it. But I cannot remember the guy's name. Sorry.

Comment: @needle, about the spacing issue: it's how the syntax is defined in vim.vim syntax file. You could find the line where that syntax is declared (starts with `syn match vimCommentTitle`) and see where in the regexp is a colon. Try adding a zero-or-many space before that colon (turn `:` into `\s*:`) and see if it works. You might need `sudoedit` if the file is readonly.

Comment: @klaus By looking into your `sy match`, i think it it possible to create a regex with what i want. I am familiar with regex in other programming languages, but vim's is quite different. Could you help me out. I want `sy match` to match things in between 1 or more `-` and ` ` (space). For example `- Hello -`, `--- Hello -`, `--     Hello     -`. But not `-Hello -`, `- Hello `, `-- Hello`...

Comment: Should be something like `-\+\s\+[^-]*\s\+-\+`. If you know regexp in other languages, I think you can decode that pattern. Try playing with it until it fits your exact need. But I would try and understand vim's default syntax pattern for commentTitle and **add** to it instead of totally **redefining** it.

Comment: @needle or, if you're editing the default file anyway, maybe you could *add your own  syntax group*? So both commentTitle and your pattern work? I don't know if that'll work. But it's worth a try.

Comment: @klaus : i tried `sy match myBoldComment '-\+\s\+[^-]*\s\+-\+' | hi myBoldComment cterm=bold gui=bold`, but i cant make it work. I also tried doing `sy match vimCommentTitle '-\+\s\+[^-]*\s\+-\+' | hi vimCommentTitle cterm=bold gui=bold`, and it still doesn't work. Also, by the looks of it, that pattern would also make the `-`, bold... If that is the case, maybe there is a non-capturing group thing to only make the things in between the `---  ---` bold?

Comment: @needle I don't know why it's not working. Did you edit the vim.vim syntax file and check afterwards if the file was saved properly? And the noncapturing group is done with `\zs` and `\ze`, e.g., `matchedbutnotcaptured\zscaptured\zenotcaptured`.